# Where can I find the Restricted Gear quality in Shadowrun?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I had a player once who used a quality called Restricted Gear (I think), which let him spend extra character points to purchase *one* item which was above the normal availability limit for a starting character. I thought that this quality came from *Arsenal*, but after having actually purchased the book, I'm unable to find it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the Runner's Companion. Restricted Gear is on page 101. It lets you buy an item up to Availability 20 for 5 BP.